# Using application.yaml property with non-bean class

Tags: spring, kotlin

I want to use property in application.yaml in static class.

The code is below.
It worked well, but I don't know it's right.

If it's not, please tell me more appropriate way.

```kotlin
object CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor : EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private const val CONFIG_PROPERTY = "foo.bar"
    var property: Boolean = true

    override fun postProcessEnvironment(environment: ConfigurableEnvironment, application: SpringApplication?) {
        property =
            StringUtils.trimWhitespace(
                environment.getProperty(CONFIG_PROPERTY) ?: run { "true" })
                .toBoolean()
    }
}

object FooUtil {
    private val property = CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor.property
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to use a property in a static class?
It may, but it is absolutely not necessarily the case, indicate issues with the design.

Comment: @IvanKrizsan For example, I need to use FooUtil.test() with spring profiles. It means that FooUtil.test() should be only worked in prod profile. I made it static class because it's just Utility class.
Should I change static class into bean?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make a regular (singleton, of course) bean out of the utility class since it would, as far as I am concerned, fit better into the Spring way of developing applications. In addition it would make it possible to inject property values in a more simple and standardized manner using @Value and it will eliminate the need for the custom environment post-processor.